# Approve/Reject many Records at once via Apex

Tags: apex, approval-process, approval-step

I have an idea of approving/rejecting multiple records via apex. I read from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm and I was able to approve/reject many records at a time.

My problem is that I used **for loop** for approving all of the records, which caused an error of **Too many SOQL queries** (which happened because each record(**Account**) is connected to 2 triggers and I used like 100 records for testing)and having the process caused the triggers to run once for every record.

Is there a way to approve/reject multiple ProcessWorkitemRequests at once? (like maybe putting them first in a list before using DML statements)

Here is my code:

```
Set<Id> accIds = (new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account])).keySet();
Set<Id> pIds = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id,Status,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObjectId in :accIds])).keySet();
Set<Id> pInstanceWorkitems = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstanceWorkitem>([SELECT Id,ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstanceId in :pIds])).keySet();

for (Id pInstanceWorkitemsId:pInstanceWorkitems){
    system.debug(pInstanceWorkitemsId);
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req2.setComments('mRequest.');
        req2.setAction('Reject');
        req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});

        // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked
        req2.setWorkitemId(pInstanceWorkitemsId);

        // Submit the request for approval
        Approval.ProcessResult result2 =  Approval.process(req2);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use list of `Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest` ? then you can use that list outside for loop for submit

Comment: I already tried that but I get 'Illegal assignment from List<Approval.ProcessResult> to Approval.ProcessResult'. 

When I changed into 'List<Approval.ProcessResult> result2 =  Approval.process(req2);' I get "Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Approval/ProcessWorkitemRequest$$r"

Comment: few days back this is what I tried.... `Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest[] lRequests = New Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest[]{};
            for(Project_Coverage_Team_Member__c objPCTMember: lstProCovTeamMemberToInsert)
            {
                Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                req1.setObjectId(objPCTMember.Id);
                lRequests.add(req1);
            }
            Approval.ProcessResult[] results =Approval.process(lRequests);` try same like for your case

Comment: Thanks for the idea...I already solved this problem using your concept!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got it. Instead of approving each record one at a time, I realized I can put all requests in a list before approving them all at once.

```
Set<Id> accIds = (new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account])).keySet();
Set<Id> pIds = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id,Status,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObjectId in :accIds])).keySet();
Set<Id> pInstanceWorkitems = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstanceWorkitem>([SELECT Id,ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstanceId in :pIds])).keySet();

List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest> allReq = new List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest>(); 
for (Id pInstanceWorkitemsId:pInstanceWorkitems){
    system.debug(pInstanceWorkitemsId);
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req2.setComments('mRequest.');
        req2.setAction('Reject'); //to approve use 'Approve'
        req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});

        // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked
        req2.setWorkitemId(pInstanceWorkitemsId);

        // Add the request for approval
        allReq.add(req2);
}
Approval.ProcessResult[] result2 =  Approval.process(allReq);
```